# put all elements of html page into the center of page

Tags: html

I've got a button, two textboxes and some text. How to put all this elements into the center of page?

```
<body>
        Hello world!
        <p><input TYPE="text" name="textbox1"><p> 
        <p><input TYPE="text" name="textbox2"></p>
        <p><input TYPE="button" VALUE="Enter" ONCLICK="HomeButton()"></p> 
            <script>
                function HomeButton()
                {
                    location.href="registration.html";
                }
            </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Vertically, horizontally or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this, or you can use external CSS Sheets :)

```
<!--In your <head> add this-->

<style type="text/css">
body{margin:0;padding:0}
#body{width:800px; margin:auto}
</style>

<!--And here is your body-->

<body>
<div id="body">
CONTENT HERE!
</div>
</body>
```

This will make a set width of 800px and then it will align it in the center of the page

Comment: Working fine for me in Google Chrome, could be a compatibility issue, you using an external sheet? or inline?

Comment: simple .html document in notepad

Comment: add your doctype as detailed here if you havent already done so, not having it can cause some issues :<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<body>
<div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
        Hello world!
        <p><input TYPE="text" name="textbox1"><p> 
        <p><input TYPE="text" name="textbox2"></p>
        <p><input TYPE="button" VALUE="Enter" ONCLICK="HomeButton()"></p> 
            <script>
                function HomeButton()
                {
                    location.href="registration.html";
                }
            </script>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wouldn't do much without adding a width. Also please don't use inline css.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. Her they explain a solution to your problem: http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/center-page-content-horizontally-and-vertically/

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
​body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

in your CSS. ​JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QXkCn/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can put these controls into `div` or using `<center>` tag or `<body align="center">`

Answer (score 1):

Use table or divs

try the below code

```
<body >
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="200">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td width="400px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td> Hello world!
            <p><input TYPE="text" name="textbox1"><p> 
            <p><input TYPE="text" name="textbox2"></p>
            <p><input TYPE="button" VALUE="Enter" ONCLICK="HomeButton()"></p> </td>

      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

for this simply use `<body align="center">`
here how it look [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5ZE8/)

Although its not a good practice but this will work,